# I am using a WPF SQL database datagrid and I want to edit rows and make them bold

Tags: c#, database, wpf, xaml

I'm using Data Grid that is being generated by a SQL database and I want make a single row bold or italics but whenever I use this method the entire datagrid becomes **bold**. Can someone help me specify the row I want?

```
    private void bold_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        gl.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    }
```

I'm using `<menucontext>` to do this:

```
    <MenuItem Name="bold" Header="_Bold" IsCheckable="True" 
              Checked="bold_Checked" Unchecked="bold_Unchecked">    
    </MenuItem>
```

I want to also use:

```
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftRightUp"  
                 Handler="DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp"/>
```

so that I can select my row and open the menu at the same time using the right mouse button

This is the code for that:

```
    private void DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                string Rowid = "";

                DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)gl.SelectedItem;
                Rowid = "" + dataRowView["EMPID"];

                txtID.Text = "" + dataRowView["EMPID"];
                txtName.Text = "" + dataRowView["EMPName"];
                combobox2.Text = "" + dataRowView["EMPRole"];
                txtAddress.Text = "" + dataRowView["EMPAddress"];
                txtEmail.Text = "" + dataRowView["EMPEmail"];
                txtNumber.Text = "" + dataRowView["EMPNumber"];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
    }
```

Here's  my entire Datagrid XAML code for more context:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="gl" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding  Path = tblEmp1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            MinHeight="100" IsReadOnly="True" 
            AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" FontSize="14"  
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Aqua" Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Aqua" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </DataGrid.Background>

                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                       
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                        <!--<EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonUp" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseRightButtonUp"-->
                        
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>

                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <MenuItem Name="edit" Header="_Edit Row"  Click="edit_Click">
                            <MenuItem Name="Format" Header="_Format Row">
                                <MenuItem Name="bold" Header="_Bold"  
                            IsCheckable="True" Checked="bold_Checked" Unchecked="bold_Unchecked" />
                                <MenuItem Name="italic" Header="_Italic" 
                          IsCheckable="True" Checked="italic_Checked" Unchecked="italic_Unchecked" >
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Name="view" Header="_View Row" Click="view_Click"  />

                            <MenuItem Name="delete" Header="_Delete 
               Employee" Click="delete_Click"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#178B4B" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="EMPID  " Binding="{Binding EMPID}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EMPName   " Binding="{Binding EMPName}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EMPRole   " Binding="{Binding EMPRole}"  />

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EMPAddress   " Binding="{Binding EMPAddress}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EMPEmail   " Binding="{Binding EMPEmail}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="EMPNumber   " Binding="{Binding EMPNumber}"  />

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Window>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: This can be achieved in XAML, but we need more data so we can be able to help you. Can you share the markup you use for the DataGrid for example? and other snippets that can help us help you. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to operate on a row, you can place your contextmenu on a row:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="rowMenu">
            <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Mark Bold"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource rowMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>
```

Then in your click-handler navigate from the menuitem to the contextmenu root to the underlying row and finally set the row font properties as needed

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var root = GetMenuRoot(sender as DependencyObject);

    if (root?.PlacementTarget is DataGridRow row)
        row.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
}

private ContextMenu GetMenuRoot(DependencyObject current)
{
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current is ContextMenu cm)
            return cm;

        current = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    return null;
}
```